# Am I correct in thinking "the lack of" should be followed by a plural noun?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I read this sentence from [here](http://www.businessinsider.com/sundance-2018-amazon-netflix-buys-2018-2018-1):

> **The lack of buying activity** by Amazon Studios and Netflix this year meant more companies got to be involved in the movie buys than in previous years.

Shouldn't it be "the lack of buying activities"?

Answer (score 1):

"lack of" can be followed by a plural **count** noun, or by a **non-count** noun (obviously in the singular).

"activity" can be countable or uncountable. The sentence in question shows it as an uncountable noun. Although "buying activity" could be understood to be made up of buying transaction**s** or buying operation**s** or buying deal**s**, the word "activity" is fine in the singular, that phrase being synonymous with:

- *The fact that Amazon Studios and Netflix were inactive as buyers (= reported no buying activity) this year...*